# Verifier for A_tm in polynomial time - how to formally prove it does not exist?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, np

How would you formally prove the non-existance of a polynomial time verifier for $A_\mathrm{TM}$?

I mean we can't just say that in order to read a certain certificate we need more than poly-time because we need to prove it for **any possible** certificate. What would be the correct proof ?

Comment: I thought about proof by contradiction- if we do have a polytime verifier then Atm is in Np --> then it has a non-deterministic machine that decides in in polyitme -->it has a determinsitic TM that decides in 2^(polytime)  --> Atm is decidable -->contradiction

Comment: This argument seems completely fine. Perhaps you'd like to answer your own question?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose by contradiction $A_\mathrm{TM}$ has polytime verifier $\Longrightarrow$ $A_\mathrm{TM}$ is in NP $\Longrightarrow$ $A_\mathrm{TM}$ is decideable by some non-deterministic TM in polytime $\Longrightarrow$ $A_\mathrm{TM}$ is dcidiable by some deterministic $2^{\mathrm{polytime}}$ TM $\Longrightarrow$ $A_\mathrm{TM}$ is decidable $\Longrightarrow$ contradiction.